# How to find the input variables for a data science work?

Tags: analytics

I am working on a classification problem. I have few tables from the database with 1000+ of columns put together. I dont know how to select the right variables which can actually contribute to the output. In otherwords, I dont know by using which variable I would be able to predict correctly. Is there anyway to identify the important variables that can be used out of these 1000+ variables.

Comment: This may be a better question for one of the statistics-based Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Are these Tables (sql)?  Or are csv, no_sql, or any kind of data?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use [Principal Component Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) to reduce your high-dimensional data into a low dimensional one using the programming language of your choice.
If you use R, try this
http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/factor.html
If you use Python, look at this
http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_pca_step_by_step.html
Hope this helps!